# It can be join the new SharePoint Server to farm after SharePoint and Cumulative Updates installed?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

Hi I prepared a server for SharePoint 2019. Can i join the server to farm that means can i run SharePoint Production Configuration Wizard after i installed like below sequence:

Prerequisites + SharePoint 2019 binaries + Language Packs + January 2019 CU for SharePoint Server 2019?

This is because i want to make a server template for use this in future to prepare new SharePoint Serves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy a reference Image for SharePoint, you need to perform some steps:

1. Build the Windows Server Image
2. Install SharePoint Server Binaries
3. Cleanup, Sysprep and Deploy

Your question described step 2. You have installed all required binaries. An optional step is installation of [AppFabric CU7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3092423/cumulative-update-7-for-microsoft-appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server).

All steps are described here in great detail: [SharePoint Server 2016: Build a Reference Image (Sysprep)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33789.sharepoint-server-2016-build-a-reference-image-sysprep.aspx)

Another reference with some technical background: [SharePoint Sysprep](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emberger/2014/09/09/sharepoint-sysprep/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can you just need to remember to update your image each time you update the farm (ie if next month you put the Feb CU you need to update your image as well if you plan to create and join more servers in the future) basically the server you are joining needs to be on same update level as the farm. You should probably put as well the CU7 for the AppFabric if you havent done that already.